# Reading Input from a pawn class C++ unreal engine 5.2 while possessed in another one

Tags: c++, game-development, unreal-engine5

I'm using the in build Car template of Unreal Engine 5.2 and a C++ pawn class. I need the steering value from Gamepad Joystick in the pawn class C++ code while driving the inbuilt Car for a reason. How could I get it?

I tried the normal way but since the pawn isn't possessed and It is not getting the input. How can I read the Gamepad left thumb stick value?

Comment: You can always read it in the player controller. Have you thought about reading the value there and transferring the information to the pawn?